# How can I keep catching exceptions, in a way that would allow me to resume whatever I'm doing?

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, exception

Sorry if the title isn't clear enough. But basically I have a method that copies `Component`s via reflection.

```
public static T GetCopyOf<T>(this Component comp, T other) where T : Component
{
    Type type = comp.GetType();
    if (type != other.GetType()) return null; // type mis-match
    BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Default;
    PropertyInfo[] pinfos = type.GetProperties(flags);
    foreach (var pinfo in pinfos) {
        if (pinfo.CanWrite)
            pinfo.SetValue(comp, pinfo.GetValue(other, null), null);
    }
    FieldInfo[] finfos = type.GetFields(flags);
    foreach (var finfo in finfos) {
        finfo.SetValue(comp, finfo.GetValue(other));
    }
    return comp as T;
}
```

Use it like: `comp1 = comp1.GetCopyOf(comp2);`

Works nice and cozy.

However, there are instances where *there is* a setter to a property (`CanWrite` is true) but the setter throws an exception, like this for example:

```
public virtual Texture mainTexture
{
    get
    {
        Material mat = material;
        return (mat != null) ? mat.mainTexture : null;
    }
    set
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException(GetType() + " has no mainTexture setter");
    }
}
```

In this case, if I get this exception, what I wanna do is to just move on to the next property (i.e. just ignore the current one - don't break)

So how can I catch this exception, in a way that would allow me to resume copying other properties? I guess it has to be a recursive method since there could be other properties that throw an exception in their setter.

Another way to express what I want is `if (there's an exception) continue;`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies, for some reason I didn't think of this:

```
    if (pinfo.CanWrite) {
        try {
            pinfo.SetValue(comp, pinfo.GetValue(other, null), null);
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Swallow the exception as follows:

```
if (pinfo.CanWrite)
{
    try
    {
        pinfo.SetValue(comp, pinfo.GetValue(other, null), null);
    }
    catch(System.NotImplementedException ex)
    { 
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I immediately thought about doing this after I asked. for some reason...

Comment: Hmm, I don't know why, but for some reason doing it like this doesn't seem to actually catch it - it still breaks. I had to do it like `catch { }` any idea why?

Comment: may be some other type of exception `(other than System.NotImplementedException)` is thrown ; In that case `catch {}` will work

Comment: I don't think so. Because in the console I still the output that a `NotImplementedException` has been thrown.